# Example how to use TCPReassembly in pcapplusplus?

Tags: tcp, pcapplusplus

I have to write TCP Reassembly code in c++. Can somebody please suggest me what is the most suitable library I can use with enough documentation. I tried `[pcapplusplus][1]` but in this library, I can't find documentation how to implement TCP reassembly, only the api reference.

https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus

So I am curious to know whelther you can give me an example tutorial on how to use `pcapplusplus` TCP Reassembly or there are are other such library available?

Comment: *"there is no documentation how to implement TCP reassembly, only the api reference."* - I’m voting to close this question because the OP did not seem to take a deeper look at the documentation. Reading the README from the linked github page explicitly mentions TCP reassembly and provides [this link](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/features#packet-reassembly) for more. There not only the API is mentioned as referenced but in the same sentence [sample implementations](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/examples#ipdefragutil) are linked as reference on how this API can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use TCP reassembly in PcapPlusPlus:**

PcapPlusPlus contains a TCP reassembly example that shows how to use the API (you can also find this example in the [documentation](https://pcapplusplus.github.io/docs/examples#tcpreassembly)):

https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/TcpReassembly

**Write your own implementation of TCP reassembly:**

You can use the PcapPlusPlus TCP reassembly implementation as a reference:

https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/blob/master/Packet%2B%2B/header/TcpReassembly.h
https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/blob/master/Packet%2B%2B/src/TcpReassembly.cpp